# Amazon EFS mounting problem. Cannot retrieve the region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I'm trying to setup AWS RFS on an EC2 server, each time I run the mount command I get

> efs error retrieving region.

The mount command I'm typing is:

```
mount -t efs -o tls fs-047b8ccc:/ efs
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you check if your DNS is enabled in your vpc?

Comment: Just checked and DNS resolution and DNS Hostnames are both enabled.

Comment: can you try to use full dns?

Comment: @iamwoor and you are not using any custom DNS settings in the VPC [DHCP Options Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html)?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Tried using full DNS, same issue 'error retrieving region'. I'm not using any custom DNS settings in the VPC. Everything is setup really simple. This is doing my head in !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently hit this myself. First, I checked to see if my EC2 instance was having trouble authenticating with AWS by attempting to [Retrieve Instance Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) and sure enough, the IMDSv1 command

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data
```

yields 401 - Unauthorized. The IMDSv2 command

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600" && \
curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

succeeded, so this made me wonder if the installed amazon-efs-utils version 1.7 package was too old to work with IMDSv2.

Reading through the [efs-utils/amazon-efs-utils package release notes](https://github.com/aws/efs-utils/blob/1a33d30b64e5a40a79799891270fe66217929e8d/amazon-efs-utils.spec#L191-L198)

```
* Thu Jun 10 2021 - 1.31.2
- Handle the fallback to IMDSv1 call when either HTTPError or unknown exception is thrown

* Thu May 06 2021 - 1.31.1
- Use IMDSv2 by default to access instance metadata service

* Fri Mar 27 2020 - 1.24.3
- Use IMDSv1 by default, and use IMDSv2 where required
```

it certainly looked like version 1.7 predates IMDSv2 support. In my case, the instance in question is not internet-facing and is slated for decommissioning, so I chose to degrade the security posture and quickly fix the problem by setting IMDSv2=Optional via configuration management. (The setting can also be modified via the AWS EC2 Console.) A better fix would have been to upgrade the amazon-efs-utils package.